# Backbone.js Handling of Attributes That Are Arrays

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I really like Backbone, but I am having the hardest time doing what would seem to be simple things. I appreciate any help with the following example.

I have a model, Criteria, that I want to use to store the state of some items in my UI. there are a couple simple attributes, and one attribute that is an array of IDs used to store the IDs of tags the user has selected in the UI.

So, I create a new instance. I add some items to the tags array. Then, I want to start fresh, create a new instance, assigned to the same variable. But, my tags array continues to hold information I added to it as a part of the first instance of Criteria.

I have documented the test case below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="Scripts/Libraries/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Libraries/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Libraries/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            // Simple model to hold some state about my UI.
            var Criteria = Backbone.Model.extend({

                defaults: {
                    "status": "Normal",
                    "priority": "Normal",
                    "tags": new Array()
                }

            });

            // Create new criteria.
            window.criteria = new Criteria();

            // The length of the tags array should be 0. PASSES
            console.log("Expect 0: Actual " + window.criteria.get("tags").length);

            // Add a tag id to the tags array.
            window.criteria.get("tags").push(5); // Tag with ID of 5.

            // The length of the tags array should be 1. PASSES
            console.log("Expect 1: Actual " + window.criteria.get("tags").length);

            // Create a new instance of criteria.
            window.criteria = new Criteria();

            // The length of the tags array should be 0. FAILS
            // CONFUSED. I thought this is now a new instance with a new set of attributes.
            // Why does the tags collection still have an item in it.
            console.log("Expect 0: Actual " + window.criteria.get("tags").length);

            // OK. So, I will call the clear method on the model. This is supposed to remove all attributes
            // from the model.
            // Then, I will create it again.
            window.criteria.clear();
            window.criteria = new Criteria();

            // The length of the tags array should be 0. FAILS. Still 1.
            console.log("Expect 0: Actual " + window.criteria.get("tags").length);

            // ARGH!
            console.log("HELP!");

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Backbone test page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I just way off the mark here? Am I trying to use Backbone for things it was not intended? Or am I missing something more general in javascript OO programming?

P.S. I originally used a Backbone collection of tags, but that presented a whole different set of issues relating to having a Tag model referenced in multiple collections and how Backbone's remove method unsets the "collection" reference when an item is removed from any collection. Another day, another issue.

Comment: Hi Kevin, perhaps you could change your accepted answer to the one below it? Which is far more legible and the recommended approach. The accepted answer is only an inflated idea of the same thing anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thom Blake is right about why it's keeping the same values for the array. one option for solving this is to set the default value in the initializer

```
        var Criteria = Backbone.Model.extend({

            defaults: {
                "status": "Normal",
                "priority": "Normal"
            },

            initialize: function(){
              if( !this.get('tags') ){ 
                this.set({tags: new Array()});
              }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up following this approach and it makes perfect sense now. So, just to make sure, the primitive values (status, priority) do not need to be reset like the tags array? Correct?

Comment: Had code like this but I had {silent: true} passed to the this.set(..., {silent: true}) call and then when I went through the changed attributes I did also see the ones I had changed with this.set(... {silent: true}) in the initialiser which wasn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 70):

"defaults" can also be a function.

```
var Criteria = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            "status": "Normal",
            "priority": "Normal",
            "tags": new Array()
        }
    }
});
```

This would create a new array when a new Criteria is instantiated.
See: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults

Comment: What's the purpose of the return?

Comment: The key is that the "defaults" property is a function now rather than an object. The return denotes an object that is returned from the function and used as the value for "defaults."

As others have explained, if "defaults" is an object, when a new model is created, each property in "defaults" is copied into the object's attributes. When the properties are Strings or Numbers, this works as expected, but for Objects and Arrays, this copy is done by reference. For each instance to have its own copy of the default attributes, you should use a function.

Comment: I much prefer this syntax, than the one from the chosen answer

Comment: Note that you can just use [] instead of "new Array()"

Comment: This is the way you should do it.
"Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all instances. Instead, define defaults as a function." - http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults

Comment: And it reads far far more easily! A change in accepted answer would be useful here.

Answer (score 13):

When you define 'tags' under 'defaults', you create a new Array and set that to the default value for that class.  Then, when you create a new instance, it has the same Array reference, which still has the things you pushed into it.

Rather than setting a default value for tags, you should be able to just set it to `[]` before you use it the first time:

```
window.criteria = new Criteria()
window.criteria.set({'tags', []})  //you can use new Array() if you want
window.criteria.get('tags').push(5)

window.criteria = new Criteria()
console.log(window.criteria.get('tags'))   //should be undefined
window.criteria.set({'tags', []})
```

Comment: I had the same problem recently when storing js Date objects as properties in the Backbone.Model type classes. I was not creating new date objects just changing a single reference. So as far as backbone was concerned the date never changed and events never fired. Rule is with backbone always treat properties as immutable values. If you need to change a property clone a new value which will create a new reference and alter the new reference.

Comment: I went ahead and followed the initialization approach below. Good explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, the last option provided by Maksym H. will not solve the problem.  The defaults property is provided assuming all of the values set are immutable.  An array, however, is mutable, meaning its value can be changed (e.g. tags[0] = "hello" can be changed with tags[0] = "hi there").

By using btford's answer, you are forcing a new instance of any mutable object/property to be created on every new instance of the model, so it is never shared, because the object is created with a function scoped variable.

Similarly,  Derick Bailey's answer is correct, it just uses the initialize method instead of the defaults method.