# Initialize Model elements in javascript/backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am getting a nested JSON data from REST. Now I want to capture that value in a variable. Everything is working fine but I don't know how should I initialize that variable.

So here is my initialize method of Model.

```
initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        if (!this.get('dropdownData')) {
                this.set({
                    dropdownData: []
                });
            }
        }
}
```

AJAX CALL:

```
fetchDropdown: function(data) {
            var self = this;
            var d = $.Deferred();
            var dropdownRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: this.urlRoot,
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            });
            dropdownRequest.done(function(data)
            {
                self.set({
                            dropdownData: data
                        });
                console.log("JSON SUCCESS!! YAY!!");
                d.resolve();

            });
```

Now `dropdownData` should be initialized as `dropdownData: {} or dropdownData: []` or I don't need to initialize it at all.

P.S: Logic wise code snippet is working. I just want to know what's the correct way to initialize the `dropdownData` in the `initialize`function in `BACKBONE MODEL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone.js Handling of Attributes That Are Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433795/backbone-js-handling-of-attributes-that-are-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding initializing `dropdownData` in the `initialize` method entirely, instead utilizing [model.defaults](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) here.  If you add the following to your model definition:

```
defaults: function () {
  return {
    dropdownData: []
  };
},
```

...then you can remove all the code in the body of your `initialize` method.  The result of this change will be that an instantiated model will either have the supplied value (at instantiation) for `dropdownData` *or* the model will default to the empty array specified.

**Note that it's important to use the function version of `defaults` here**.  If you were to do this instead:

```
defaults: {
  dropdownData: []
},
```

...then any instantiated model *not supplied with a value for `dropdownData`* would share a value for `dropdownData`.  Every instance would refer to the exact same array.

Comment: Can you kindly help me with this query :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852177/how-to-reload-the-page-as-per-the-dropdown-in-javascript-backbone